# ghost line does nothing even when viewing through the Node debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-authentication, chrome-debugging

I have the weirdest bug I have ever seen.  I recently upgraded my config package and my Google strategy started failing.

I used the debugger to troubleshoot this error:

[image]

In the debugger I got to the line were the internal authorizationURL is supposed to be set:

[image]

I even set a watch on it ( it is a property on the options object )

[image]

Here is a closeup of the line that does nothing, I call it the ghost line:

[image]

I stepped through the code line by line and that particular line does nothing for some reason.

For a reality check I put it in a fiddle / replit:

https://repl.it/@johnmorsey/OpenQueasyHashmap

I have no idea how updating my config package has caused this internal error in Passport - Google Strategy.

In my mind the authorizationURL is clearly an internal property that is being set though "ghosting" in the debugger.  But in reality my app is crashing b.c. of the error.

Comment: What is `options` because it doesn't seem to be a simple object ? The described effect can be caused by something other then just that line not being executed, for example https://repl.it/repls/LumpyEthicalScandisk

Comment: Well ... yes ... need to ask the authors of node-config why they are returning this "monster" object to break Passport-Google code.

Comment: Ran out of tags but this object came from node-config package passed to Passport-Google package.